# MySQL - Show All Permutations?

Tags: sql, database, mysql

Table1:

```
Id   MyFK   f_name   l_name
===========================
1    100    John     Doe
2    100    Little   Timmy
```

Table2:

```
Id   MyFK   item     price
===========================
1    100    Car      200
2    100    Bike     100
```

In MySQL, how do I produce a table like this:

```
Id   MyFK   f_name   l_name  item  price
========================================
1    100    John     Doe     Car   200
1    100    John     Doe     Bike  100
2    100    Little   Timmy   Car   200
2    100    Little   Timmy   Bike  100
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE person
SELECT 1 AS Id, 100 AS MyFK, 'John' AS f_name, 'Doe' AS l_name UNION
SELECT 2, 100, 'Little', 'Timmy';

CREATE TABLE vehicle
SELECT 1 AS Id, 100 AS MyFK, 'Car' AS item, 200 AS price UNION
SELECT 2, 100, 'Bike', 100;

SELECT p.Id, p.MyFK, p.f_name, p.l_name, v.item, v.price
FROM person p
CROSS JOIN vehicle v;
```

Comment: This is an old answer but as I got here 10 years later others may get too. I just wanted to add the `CROSS JOIN` is the key to achieve the permutations. Without an `ON` condition, it combines all the records from one table with those from another.

Answer (score -1):

Use a join to join the tables on a field which will give the result you are after.  In this instance use the MyFK field on each table so you would use:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.MyFK = Table2.MyFK
```

That gives the result you are after.

Comment: He's asking for all the possible **permutations** :-?