# Take Column username in each row and split each username into player_1 Player_2

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called users in that I have id auto inc primary key , username , password , email , admin_level

I want to loop each username and insert them into new table called matchups

table matchups has tournament_id , player_1 , player_2. I need to split each username from previous table and have each username be assigned player_1 and player_2

end result to have a player vs player matchup as they signup

Comment: You seem to suggest that you will put the usernames of the users into the matchups table. You should instead put in the IDs of the users and then JOIN the tables in later queries.

Answer (score 0):

OK... Normally transferring data from one SQL table to another is better done within the SQL language itself, so let's look at how we can do that (I have never dealt with a problem like this before, so I am learning as I go).

My Test Table `players`, for reference, was:

```
`player_id` `name`
1           Robert Doe
2           John Smith
```

### Make All Possible Permutations of Players

First, trying to find the potential permutations of two players.

I found a SO Question which was similar, but dealt with two tables interacting. [MySQL - Show All Permutations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475766/mysql-show-all-permutations). MySQL can use one table twice in the same query, we just need to set aliases for each of them so they don't clash.

```
SELECT `p1`.`player_id` , `p1`.`name` , `p2`.`player_id` , `p2`.`name`
FROM `players` AS `p1`
CROSS JOIN `players` AS `p2`
```

This produced the following:

```
`p1`.`player_id` `p1`.`name` `p2`.`player_id` `p2`.`name`
1                Robert Doe  1                Robert Doe
1                Robert Doe  2                John Smith
2                John Smith  1                Robert Doe
2                John Smith  2                John Smith
```

OK... Unless people are playing against themselves, this will not do, so we better eliminate any rows where both sides are the same.

**NOTE:** Skip ahead to "**Eliminate Self-Matches & Duplicate, but Reversed, Matches - Amended Solution**" for a more efficient version of the following steps. (*Older solution kept here to show my own learning through this problem.*)

### Eliminate Self-Matches

```
SELECT `p1`.`player_id` , `p1`.`name` , `p2`.`player_id` , `p2`.`name`
FROM `players` AS `p1`
CROSS JOIN `players` AS `p2`
WHERE `p1`.`player_id`!=`p2`.`player_id`
```

This produced the following:

```
`p1`.`player_id` `p1`.`name` `p2`.`player_id` `p2`.`name`
1                Robert Doe  2                John Smith
2                John Smith  1                Robert Doe
```

Much better. Now, this is good, and is perfect if, for instance, every player/team plays each other twice (for instance, if they have a home and an away game against each other), but if these are one-off matchups, we need to figure out how to filter out the duplicate matches.

### Eliminate Duplicate, but Reversed, Matches

Each member has an id number, and numbers, being, well, numbers, can be easily compared against each other and sorted. To do that compare and sort, on a per row basis, we need to use the `CASE` conditional. ([SQL MAX of multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns))

```
SELECT `p1`.`player_id` , `p1`.`name` , `p2`.`player_id` , `p2`.`name` ,
       CASE WHEN `p1`.`player_id`<`p2`.`player_id`
         THEN CONCAT( `p1`.`player_id` , '|' , `p2`.`player_id` )
         ELSE CONCAT( `p2`.`player_id` , '|' , `p1`.`player_id` )
       END AS `uniqueMatch`
FROM `players` AS `p1`
CROSS JOIN `players` AS `p2`
WHERE `p1`.`player_id`!=`p2`.`player_id`
```

Which returns

```
`p1`.`player_id` `p1`.`name` `p2`.`player_id` `p2`.`name` `uniqueMatch`
2                John Smith  1                Robert Doe 1|2
1                Robert Doe  2                John Smith 1|2
```

Now all we have to do group the rows by those matches

```
SELECT `p1`.`player_id` , `p1`.`name` , `p2`.`player_id` , `p2`.`name` ,
       CASE WHEN `p1`.`player_id`<`p2`.`player_id`
         THEN CONCAT( `p1`.`player_id` , '|' , `p2`.`player_id` )
         ELSE CONCAT( `p2`.`player_id` , '|' , `p1`.`player_id` )
       END AS `uniqueMatch`
FROM `players` AS `p1`
CROSS JOIN `players` AS `p2`
WHERE `p1`.`player_id`!=`p2`.`player_id`
GROUP BY `uniqueMatch`
```

Which returns:

```
`p1`.`player_id` `p1`.`name` `p2`.`player_id` `p2`.`name` `uniqueMatch`
2                John Smith  1                Robert Doe 1|2
```

And adding another row to the table to check it behaves itself:

```
`p1`.`player_id` `p1`.`name`  `p2`.`player_id` `p2`.`name` `uniqueMatch`
2                Robert Doe   1                John Smith  1|2
3                Matt Citizen 1                John Smith  1|3
3                Matt Citizen 2                Robert Doe  2|3
```

### Eliminate Self-Matches & Duplicate, but Reversed, Matches - Amended Solution

With many thanks to David Winant, the solution could be shorted somewhat. Rather than using the `CASE THEN CONCAT( ... ) ELSE ...` we can apply a simple additional check to the `WHERE` clause to ensure that we only get one set of matched players. Again, as we know that the player's IDs will be diferent, and as such one will be greater than the other, we can check that is the case to eliminate half the returned rows.

```
SELECT `p1`.`player_id` , `p1`.`name` , `p2`.`player_id` , `p2`.`name`
FROM `players` AS `p1`
CROSS JOIN `players` AS `p2`
WHERE `p1`.`player_id`<`p2`.`player_id`
```

Which returns

```
`p1`.`player_id` `p1`.`name`  `p2`.`player_id` `p2`.`name`
1                John Smith   2                Robert Doe
1                John Smith   3                Matt Citizen
2                Robert Doe   3                Matt Citizen
```

Again, thank you to David Winant for identifying this amendment and sharing it with me - now I have learnt even more in helping out with this problem.

Excellent! Now, we can use these results to automatically INSERT into another table:

### Inserting the Results into Another Table

If we were doing it manually, we'd use something like:

```
INSERT INTO `matches` ( `id_player1` , `id_player2` ) VALUES ( 2 , 1 ) , ( 3 , 1 ) ...
```

But, we can use the above `SELECT` query to take care of all the `VALUES` bit:

```
INSERT INTO `matches`
  ( `id_player1` , `id_player2` )
  SELECT `p1`.`player_id` , `p2`.`player_id`
  FROM `players` AS `p1`
  CROSS JOIN `players` AS `p2`
  WHERE `p1`.`player_id`<`p2`.`player_id`
```

Which produces the table:

```
`id_match` `id_player1` `id_player2`
1          2            1
2          3            1
3          3            2
```

And, voila, you have it!

### Incremental Addition for New Player

The above works from an established table of players (which is fine in instances where everyone registers before a deadline and the matchups are then calculated), but for instances where new users/players are added afterwards, the following code can be used to add the new matches.

```
INSERT INTO `matches` ( `id_player1` , `id_player2` )
  SELECT 123 , `player_id`
  FROM `players`
  WHERE `player_id`!=123
```

Where `123` is the `player_id` of the newly added player.

Comment: Lucanos, I like your well laid-out approach.  After your second step, though, try using p1.player_id < p2.player_id rather than the complicated joining grouping and filtering.

Comment: @David: Excellent! I'll adjust the answer to reflect that piece of brilliance.

Comment: @Jamie: This solution will create the matchups for an existing set of users/players/members. For any players joining afterwards, you would simply create a set of tuples (rows) with the new user's ID as `id_player1` and each of the other existing players as `id_player2`. (Added incremental additions SQL to the answer.)

Comment: @Jamie: Well, the PHP is something different. The SQL I have provided is accurate, and is what you were asking for in this question. So it is correct - Why did you remove the checkmark from this answer? If you need help with your PHP, that would be a new question.